# How is native code handled by the JVM

Tags: jvm, native

Consider an case that I have to call C++ code from my Java Program. The C++ code creates thousands of Objects. Where are these dynamic objects stored ? I suspect in the JVM heap because the native code will be a part of the same process as the JVM.

If yes, do the rules of Java Garbage collector thread apply on Objects of the C++ code ?

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, C++ will allocate resources using its own runtime which has nothing to do with the JVM - the JVM is not aware of any activity in this memory allocator.

For the second question, the Java garbage collector will not GC the memory allocated by C++.  You will have to make sure that your Java wrapper initiates the memory release.  Before an object is GC'd by java, the runtime calls the `finalize()` method.  The default one is inherited from java.lang.Object and basically does nothing.  You can override this and use it as a hook to initiate deallocating your manually managed memory.

Comment: @Geek - yes. It's all part of the same process, so a crash in your C++ will take down the JVM

Comment: Yes, it runs in the same process as the JVM and most certainly can crash the process.

Comment: Thanks Brian and CTW. I don't understand. How is it possible to have One Process and have memory allocation different for C++ and Java. Is Heap Memory not a part of the Address space of a Process. I think only the objects on Stack are a part of the address space. Please comment.

Comment: Heap memory is certainly within the address space of the process.  Behind the scenes, both the JVM and C++ runtime request chunks of memory from the O/S using system calls such as sbrk().  As long as they stay within the bounds of the chunks that they request they won't trip over each other.

Comment: Thanks CTW, your answers were very informative. Where can I read more about it.

Comment: Depending on what platform you are using a good system internals book such as Stevens' 'Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment' for Unix or Petzold or Richter for Windows should give you a good feel for the system level machinations.  There are quite a few JVM internals books in print, but unfortunately I haven't read any of them.  Googling for jvm, garbage collecting, finalize(), jni (Java Native Interface) and other related keywords should give you plenty of web resources on the subject.

Comment: I am no C++ expert but why C++ needs a runtime like Java? Isn't it already compiled to machine code? Is it because it's within the JVM?

Comment: @stdout - There is a core runtime that handles items like memory allocation, file system access.  C has libcrt0 and libc, and there is equivalent infrastructure for C++.